# Exercise package : link between exercises and answers. Issue with chapters

Tags: exercises, hyperlink

I would like to create links between answers and exercices using the exercise package. I reset the exercise counter at the beginning of a chapter.

But sometimes the hyperlink is not valid (shuffles between chapters). For example, in the following MWE, [Sol 1] after the exercise 1 of chapter 1 points to the solution of the exercise 1 in chapter 2.
How could I fix it ? Moreover, if there is no answer, would it be possible to hide [sol ****] in the right margin ? ([Sol 3] for exercises 1 and 2 in the MWE) [image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkcolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage[answerdelayed,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\arabic{Exercise}}
%
\newenvironment{exo}[1][\unskip]{%
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]

\normalmarginpar
\marginnote{\footnotesize\sffamily
[Sol~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}]}
}{%
\end{Exercise}
}
%
\newenvironment{sol}{\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]}
{\end{Answer}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{ABCD}

\begin{exo}
    ABCD
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
ABD 
\end{sol}


\section{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\chapter{ABCD}

\begin{exo}
    ABCD
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
ABD 
\end{sol}

\section{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
```

resets the counter of the exercise every time the chapter counter increases. This gives you the numbering of the exercise to be always 1 even if the chapter increases. However by doing this all the labels of the exercise are the same.

To solve the problem, you just need to change

```
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{Exercise}}]
```

to

```
\begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{chapter}}]
```

so that the right increasing numbering (with the chapter) is obtained.

**EDIT**

I have been a bit sloppy in the response above, as I really only fixed the very specific problem you mentioned but I did not look into the situation where you have multiple exercises/answers in each chapter. I changed the code a bit to fix that and added the possibility of having/not having the Sol. printed at the margin. See if this works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkcolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcounter{Answer}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\arabic{Exercise}}
\newcounter{myexerciselabel}
\newcounter{myexercisenumber}[chapter]
%
\newenvironment{exo}[2][\unskip]{\stepcounter{myexerciselabel}\stepcounter{myexercisenumber}
    \begin{Exercise}[title={#1},label={\the\value{myexerciselabel}}, number={\the\value{myexercisenumber}}, counter={myexercisenumber}]
        \normalmarginpar
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{#2}}{\marginnote{\footnotesize\sffamily [Sol~\refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel}]}}{}
    }{%
    \end{Exercise}
}
%
\newenvironment{sol}{\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]}
    {\end{Answer}
}


\begin{document}

    \chapter{ABCD}

    \begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
        ABCD
    \end{exo}
    \begin{sol}
        ABD 
    \end{sol}

    \begin{exo}[No Sol]{false}
        EFGH
    \end{exo}
    \begin{sol} % THIS WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED 
        EFG 
    \end{sol}

    \begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
        HIJK
    \end{exo}
    \begin{sol}
        HIJ 
    \end{sol}


    \section{Solutions}
    \shipoutAnswer

    \chapter{ABCD}

    \begin{exo}[No Sol]{false}
        ABCD
    \end{exo}
    \begin{sol}  % THIS WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED 
        ABD 
    \end{sol}

    \begin{exo}[Shows Sol]{true}
        EFGH
    \end{exo}
    \begin{sol}
        EFG 
    \end{sol}

    \section{Solutions}
    \shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

You can change the `ifthenelse` to something more advanced like the [package xargs](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/xargs/xargs.pdf) if you want to customize the parameters, have default values, etc. There are numerous examples on how to use this.

Comment: Thank you geguze ! I have completed my question with a second part : if there is no answer, would it be possible to hide [sol ****] in the right margin ?